# how to insert values with comma?in switch statement

Tags: php, mysql

i am using switch statements to insert comma values:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('config1.php');

$category_id    = 1;
$AnswerID       = $_POST['AnswerID'];
$questionid     = $_POST['questionid'];
$timetaken      = $_POST['timetaken'];
$limit          = $_POST['limit'];

echo "$limit";
$bd = "$limit";

switch ($bd) {
    case"1":
        $sql = "INSERT INTO results (id, user_id, category_id, q_id, answer_id, time_taken)
            VALUES (',', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '$category_id', '$questionid', '$AnswerID', '$timetaken')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

        $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
            echo "Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
        // Set session variables
        $_SESSION["last_id"] = "$last_id";
        break;

    case"2":
        quiz_test();
        break;

    case"3":
        quiz_test();
        break;

    case"4":
        quiz_test();
        break;

    case"5":
        quiz_test();
        unset($_SESSION['last_id']);
        break;

    default:
        echo "something is wrong";
}
function quiz_test(){
    $sql = "SELECT q_id, answer_id, time_taken FROM results WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["last_id"] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $qid=$rows['q_id'];
            $ans=$rows['answer_id'];
            $time=$rows['time_taken'];
        }
    }
    $conn->query("update results set q_id =('$questionid','$qid'),answer_id = ('$AnswerID','$ans'),time_taken=('$timetaken','$time') where id = '" . $_SESSION["last_id"] . "'");
}
?>
```

In case 1 insert values and get insert id,and set into session.

Case 2 select,update statement are not working.i got following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 62

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 62

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 63

Notice: Undefined variable: conn in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 70

Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 70
```

Comment: did you checked session variable (last_id). it is really set by your code. echo your session id to check. Pass connection to your function : quiz_test($conn);

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one parameter $conn in your function quiz_test() then it will works

Try below code

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<?php
include('config1.php');
$category_id = 1;
$AnswerID = $_POST['AnswerID'];
$questionid = $_POST['questionid'];
$timetaken = $_POST['timetaken'];
$limit = $_POST['limit'];

echo "$limit";

$bd = "$limit";
switch ($bd) {
case"1":
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (id, user_id, category_id, q_id, answer_id, time_taken)
VALUES (',', '".$_SESSION['id']."', '$category_id', '$questionid', '$AnswerID', '$timetaken')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
 $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    echo "Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
// Set session variables
$_SESSION["last_id"] = "$last_id";
break;
case"2":
quiz_test($conn);
break;
case"3":
quiz_test($conn);
break;
case"4":
quiz_test($conn);
break;
case"5":
quiz_test($conn);
unset($_SESSION['last_id']);
break;
default:
        echo "something is wrong";
}
function quiz_test($conn){
$sql = "SELECT q_id, answer_id, time_taken FROM results WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["last_id"] . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $qid=$rows['q_id'];
  $ans=$rows['answer_id'];
  $time=$rows['time_taken'];
}
}
$conn->query("update results set q_id =('$questionid','$qid'),answer_id = ('$AnswerID','$ans'),time_taken=('$timetaken','$time') where id = '" . $_SESSION["last_id"] . "'");
}
?>
```

Comment: thank's for your answer!, but it's not working i got:<br>`Notice: Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 50`
Notice: Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 51
Notice: Undefined variable: rows in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 52
Notice: Undefined variable: questionid in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 55
Notice: Undefined variable: AnswerID in C:\xampp\htdocs\N\exam\exam\DOCS\Insert.php on line 55

Comment: @NaveenGolla this is a completely different question to what you have asked! And you could also make some effort to spot the typo: $row vs $rows.

Comment: @NaveenGolla Have a look at my answer which will address some of these errors.  Really, your code has too many problems, and you should ask a new question after getting the specific answer here.

Comment: @NaveenGolla again, this is a different question, pls post it separately from this one!

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be mixing together two different flavors of PHP API functions.  You also, in your call to `mysqli_insert_id()` you should not be specifying the `id` if it is an autoincrement column.  I believe you intended to do something along these lines:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO results (user_id, category_id, q_id, answer_id, time_taken)
    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$category_id', '$questionid', '$AnswerID', '$timetaken')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
echo "Last inserted ID is: " . $last_id;
```

And the other problem as @Krish pointed out is that you need to pass your connection variable `$conn` to the `quiz_test()` function, e.g.

```
function quiz_test($conn) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Although this is true, it is not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Code for quiz_test() is there in the question. Root cause is already described in the other answer.

Comment: It does happen to all of us :)